# Springboot filter executed in case of permitAll urls as well

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, api-authorization

I am new to springboot and trying to implement security where no filters are applied to my login, signup and home urls.

I am using springboot 2.7.1

I am expecting `antMatchers("/**/signup").permitAll()` to remain free of any security filter.

Upon debugging, I found that my signup url was being hit and user details were saved, but my AuthorizationFilter was also being executed .

This is my SecurityFilterChain :

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder=http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userLoginService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager=authenticationManagerBuilder.build();

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager))
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        return http.build();
    }
```

I don't understand why is it happening this way.

Comment: Writing custom security filters are bad practice

Comment: I'm pretty new to springboot , how else should I implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `permitAll()` you are not disabling the filters, you are just specifying that you do not want to apply any authorization checks for that `RequestMatcher`. All the filters will still work.

The `AuthorizationFilter` will be invoked but since you configure `permitAll()` for that endpoint, it will always grant access.